# When is a sum of subspaces equal to the entire vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

Suppose that you have $n$ subspaces of a vector space $V$, labeled $U_i$ for $1\leq i\leq n$. When is the sum of these subspaces equal to $V$?

[This source](http://mathonline.wikidot.com/direct-sum-theorems) seems to imply that if the sum of these subspaces is a direct sum, then the direct sum equals $V$. But from what I am able to gather, the direct sum of subspaces is only equal to $V$ iff the *sum* is equal to $V$ and the sum is direct.

In any case, how do I determine whether or not a direct sum of subspaces is equal to the containing vector space?

Comment: I don't think you can in general. The most you could do is use dimensionality in the sense that if the $U_j$ are direct and the sums of their dimensions is that of $V,$ but this can be greatly relaxed, although that will make the statement a tautology.

Comment: The reason I ask is that if I have a linear transformation $T\colon V\to W$, then there exists a subspace $U\subset V$ such that $V=\ker{T}\oplus U$, but I'm not clear as to how this is true.

Comment: Given a vector space and a linearly independent set $\mathrm{B}_0,$ there exists a set $\mathrm{B}$ that contains $\mathrm{B}_0$ and is a _basis_; also every vector space has a basis. Consider $\mathrm{B}_0$ a basis for the kernel of $T$ and then $\mathrm{U}$ to be the linear span of $\mathrm{B} - \mathrm{B}_0.$